# WebsitePanel: Programmatically add/remove domains alias

Tags: windows, api, iis

I need to implement a way to integrate my code so that I could add and remove domain aliases for a single site in WebsitePanel.
I have tried to check [WebsitePanel's API](http://www.websitepanel.net/files/WebsitePanel%20Integration%20API.pdf), but it seems to be very limited and doesn't allow any management of sites and their domains.

Any ideas how I could do it in some other way?

I was thinking about adding domain alias directly to the site configured in the IIS (7), but I might need to add mail accounts and manage the DNS of the domain alias in the future so it doesn't seem like a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue: I'm trying the 'wget' approach. Login can be done using Default.aspx?pid=Login&user=USER&password=PWD

Then go to the Domain area for each client, and post some data (seems to be the same for each client/domain, can be easily read from the form/input id), to get to the DNS management web.

It's way late, and it's not just "do this", but hey, it is a starting point until something better appears.

Comment: I've considered this workaround, but it was too "hacky" to implement. I wasn't sure that WebsitePanel wouldn't change anything in their code in the future versions that would break this approach.

Comment: Totally agree with you. Haven't found any other approach, though :/.